# Angular 2 ngFor giving more iterations than expected

Tags: angular, ngfor

In my angular 2 app I have array with some items. I'm expecting to have only 1 div with ngFor but its generation 9 empty divs instead.

component.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let item of items" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">
      <div class="card card-accent-primary">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
               {{item.title}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p style="text-align: right;"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-sm"></i>&nbsp;{{item.dateAjout}}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
            <hr>
          <p>{{item.description}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--/.col-->
</div>
```

this my component.ts:

```
export class OffresEntrepriseComponent implements OnInit {
  private subscription: Subscription;
  private offreIndex: number;
  items: any[] = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private myService: MyServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: any) => {
         this.offreIndex = params['id'];
        });
        this.myService.getOffreById(this.offreIndex)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            const myArray = [];
            for (let key in data) {
                myArray.push(data[key]);
                console.log(data[key]);
            }
            this.items = myArray;
          }
        );}}
```

And finally my service :

```
public getOffreById(id: number): any{
    return this.http.get(this.url+"/Offres/"+id)
      .map((data: Response) => data.json());
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try and see what data is: this.myService.getOffreById(this.offreIndex)
        .subscribe(
          data => { console.log(data); // This will give you a hint. If your getting invalid data, then your error is your backed.

Comment: Do you unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy ?

Comment: @harold_mean2 its giving me good data.. thats weird

Comment: @DmitryGrinko No i dont have ngOnDestroy

Comment: @user3816341 it is in vain

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
    this.offreIndex = params['id'];
    this.myService.getOffreById(this.offreIndex)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.items = myArray;
      }
    );
 }
}
```

You may have to implement OnChanges on the same component also.

```
ngOnChanges(){
   this.ngOnInit();
}
```

If still does not work, try to use

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params=> {
        let searchStr = params['id'];  
        this.productQuery = new ProductQuery(searchStr, 'sub-category', 'computers', 
        false, 'electronic');
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);  
    });
}
```

The above code is what I used to display when I search a product in my and it works in my code.  Add this to your constructor if needed:  constructor(private route: `ActivatedRoute){}`. I hope this helps. Have a nice day.

Comment: You shouldn't call ```ngOnInit();```. It's an Angular core method and part of the component lifecycle. You should create a separate method and call that instead in both ```ngOnInit()``` and ```ngOnChanges()``` if you need to. 

It will probably work like that but it's a really bad practice.